# I'm still new, trying to understand how to position my pics and text items

Tags: css, positioning

So here is the landing page I'm working on.  Just a fun page trying to entice people to go into space :)

http://nyhunter77.github.io/businessPage/

I figure it's easier to just let you guys see the whole thing.
I've just started out laying out items on my page today and I'm having a hard time with the top row of items.

If you see it correctly, there is a plane on the left, the airforce symbol should be in the center, and I want the quote on the right.

It all fit together when I started until I got to the quote. 
I was using the images as multiple background images but the word block elements overlapped the images when I got to that point and covered them up.

A post here for someone else suggested going back to just using the images as img inline to have better control.  So far it's been tougher this way.

Suggestions?  Thanks!

As per someone's request - posting code ... HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="topbar">
    <div id="shuttle" style="display: inline">
        <img src="images/shuttle.jpg" style="display: inline; height: 155px">
    </div>
    <div id="airforce" style="display: inline">
        <img src="images/airforce.gif" style="display: inline; height: 155px">
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline">
        <p id="quote" style="margin-right: 50px;"> "Flying the Sci-Fi skies <br/>
        <p id="quote" style="margin-right: 85px;"> since 2012!" </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="topbarLeft">
    <!-- Logo for Space Plane should go here.  -->
    <a id="logobutton" href="index.html">Space Plane Airlines</a>
</div>
<div class="topbarRight">
    <a id="help" href="www.google.com">Help</a>
    <a id="contact" href="www.google.com">Contact Us</a>
    <a id="signIn" href="www.google.com">Sign In</a>
    <a id="join" href="www.google.com">Join</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topbar {
/* background: url("images/shuttle.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat, url("images/airforce.gif") 50% 0 no-repeat; */
width: 100%;
height: 175px;
background-size: auto 75%;
/* display: inline; */

/* background: url("images/airforce.gif") 0 0 no-repeat;
width: 300px;
height: 175px;
background-size: auto 75%; */
}

#quote {
text-align: right;
font-size: 2.5em;
list-style-type: none;
font-family: cursive, arial, times;
padding-top:15px;
/* float: right; */
}

.topbarLeft {
text-align: left;
display: inline;
/* float: left; */
}

#logobutton {
font-family: cursive, arial, times;
font-size: 2.5em;
text-decoration: none;
border: 2px solid black;
background: url("images/clouds.jpg") 0 0 no-repeat;
margin-left: 4px;
padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}

#logobutton:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.topbarRight {
text-align: right;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}
```

Comment: _"I figure it's easier to just let you guys see the whole thing."_ Please post your code in your question.

Comment: You used Comic Sans. That's enough reason for me to boycott helping you.

Comment: If I did it was just a backup ... u should see i have used cursive, arial, times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps take out the `display: inline;` and instead put `float: left;` in `#shuttle` and `#airforce`, and `float: right;` in the div that contains the two quotes. Then add a `width: 40%` to `#shuttle` to play with positioning the center image:

CSS:

```
#shuttle {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}

#airforce {
  float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="float: right;">
```

I would also suggest giving that third div a name and not use inline styles.

Comment: Thank you very much, I know I'm asking easy level questions but I didn't even know you could set 2 items to float: left;   - What a great idea!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but think you should use Google to your advantage. There are css tutorials absolutely everywhere I seriously doubt anyone here will take the time to help you, for that reason alone. Sorry.

## EDIT

I felt bad so I started trying to reform your code to reflect your idea of what you wanted, however after 3 lines I gave up. Instead I will outline your many errors in the hope you might take my advise and do some more reading as you have obviously not picked up the basics yet.

1- Images require alt tags in order to be valid EG:

```
    <img src="images/shuttle.jpg" alt="Some description of shuttle.jpg in order to explain what the image is to the visually impaired and Google">
```

2- You have place your images inside a  just so you can structure your page, however I would suggest just applying a class to the image tag its self and completely get rid of the unnecessary Div tags.

```
     <div id="shuttle" style="display: inline">
    <img src="images/shuttle.jpg" style="display: inline; height: 155px">
     </div>
```

To this:

```
    <img class="alignleft" src="images/shuttle.jpg" alt="blah" height="155" width="150">
```

Specifying width's and height's helps pass Google validation rules.

3- Multiple use's of the same ID, and again you've placed this inside a redundant DIV tag.

```
<p id="quote" style="margin-right: 50px;"> "Flying the Sci-Fi skies <br/>
    <p id="quote" style="margin-right: 85px;"> since 2012!" </p>
```

Where really

```
 <p id="quote"> Flying the Sci-Fi skies since 2012! </p>
```

Is more correct.

4- List of links, should be in a list.

```
<div class="topbarRight">
<a id="help" href="www.google.com">Help</a>
<a id="contact" href="www.google.com">Contact Us</a>
<a id="signIn" href="www.google.com">Sign In</a>
<a id="join" href="www.google.com">Join</a>
</div>
```

To this.

```
<ul class="menulist">
    <li><a href="#">Help</a><li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm sure I've missed some and I haven't even bothered looking at your Css as I feel you should get the HTML down before moving to your Css. Also... Your design is ugly with copyrighted images.

You linked to google.com a lot in your code maybe you should follow one of your links?

https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20tutorials&safe=active

http://www.w3schools.com/css/

1. Create a design your happy with, on paper, gimp/photoshop or even MS Paint if you must.
2. Get your basic HTML Markup written.
3. THEN Move onto your Css, using your Mock-up images as a guide.

Good luck.

## EDIT 2

Personally my work flow always starts with a picture, just a little sketch on a scrap of paper is usually enough. I'll make a few different ones and then pick my favorite. Then I'll open Gimp and bash it together in there. Hand drawn sketches look nice and are quick but sometimes only then when you digital-ise it do you find some parts won't actually work right on the screen. Then once you have that you should know if you need a Header, Navigation, 1 2 3 Main content sections, maybe a side bar, footer and what ever else. Then starting from back to front and top to bottom I'll get the css Basics together. So initially I'll just start with the basic layout of all my sections. I tend to give them all contrasting background colors so I can easily tell them apart. Obviously you will need to go back and change your HTML as you work on your CSS, but if you have the basics in place it makes working in CSS and easier and happier environment. My faveroite place for CSS and HTML guides is http://www.w3schools.com/ I just search for the specific tags I need. I also remember reading a introduction to HTML5 a year ago which I found on Google and if towards the end of development I need something a little fancier I will Google for the specific thing.

Learn to love the w3schools.com site as I think even the most advanced developers check back there every now and again.

Comment: I've tried a few tutorials and the Howe book but I haven't gotten the desired result yet.

Comment: That's ok, I appreciate all the tips. I'm learning this on my own so I know a lot may be wrong.  I am counting on good criticism like this to get things right.  Thanks.  I copied all that you said and I'm going to make some changes.

Comment: This question is back to @Doug. Where did you learn your semantics and can you give me some sources to learn it right? Also, I'm restarting my project and going to try beginning and working the way you suggested. A page for a home builder company, more realistic. If I understand you right, you would suggest doing all the HTML first? and then do the CSS?  I would think you have to do it together to see how the page is coming out. I'm going to draw it out first too. Thanks. Any other tips are welcome.

Comment: Thanks @Doug, I'm understanding fast the tips you've given me, after drawing out a new page and coding it very cleanly I might add, I think it's a very good lesson. I thought the divs were always needed and I've read some semantics articles that talk about that "illness" some ppl have. Anyway, here's just a snippit of my code to show you what I've learned:  oops looks like I can't post it here. You can see it at nyhunter77.github.io/businessPage2/  ... Thanks !

Comment: No problem mate, it was only a year ago I got into all this so it is all still fresh in my mind too. A up vote wouldn't go a miss ;-)